# A few questions about Play2 and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0

I am beginner of Hibernate4. I am configured Play 2.2.4 with Hibernate 4.3.6 entitymanager and write a test application. So, I have Entity class `Subject.java`

```
package models.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import play.data.validation.Constraints;

@Entity
@Table(name="subjects")
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @Column(name="sub_pcode")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="sub_name")
    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Subject() {
        id = 0;
    }

    public void save() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        if (id == 0) {
            em.persist(this);      
        } else {
            em.merge(this);
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();     
    }

    public void delete() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Subject tmpSubject = em.find(Subject.class, id);
        if (tmpSubject != null) {
            em.remove(tmpSubject);      
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();     
    }

    public static Subject get(int id) {
        Subject result;
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        result = em.find(Subject.class, id);      
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<Subject> fetchAll() {
        List<Subject> result = new ArrayList<>();
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Subject s");
        result = q.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

And controller class `Application.java`

```
package controllers;

import models.entities.Subject;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.index;
import views.html.list;


public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    public static Result addSubject() {
        Subject s = new Subject();
        s.name = "test subject";
        s.save();
        return ok(list.render(Subject.fetchAll()));
    }

    public static Result deleteSubject(int id) {
        Subject s = Subject.get(id);
        if (null != s) {
            s.delete();
        }
        return ok(list.render(Subject.fetchAll()));
    }

    public static Result updateSubject(int id) {
        Subject s = Subject.get(id);
        if (null != s) {
            s.name = "new subject";
            s.save();
        }
        return ok(list.render(Subject.fetchAll()));
    }

}
```

All I want is to ask a few questions:

1. Why I can merge entity (in `save()` method) without attaching, but
   if I wand to delete entity (by the `delete()` method) - I need to
   find entity first or I have an exception about deleting detached
   entity?
2. Seems like from controller classess I can use JPA.em() with
   @Transactional annotation to simplify work with hibernate. Is any
   simplest way to work with hibernate transactions and entitymanagers
   from non-controller classess?
3. If my code bad-styled, can anybody give me good advice about strategy of 
   hibernate usage and so on?
   Best regards. Thanks for your advices and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your EntityManagerFactory emf should not be created every time. EntityManagerFactory are thread safe and you should use it as static. If create it every time your performance will drop.
2. Entity should not handle transactions, they are used only to reflect the database data. The correct way of using an Entity would be in a repository/DAO classes.
3. Why are you doing `id = 0;` in your constructor? The default is already 0.
4. Do not open a transaction in a Controller. Controller should handle only what gets in and what gets out of the project. If you add transaction in it you will be adding unnecessary complexity and increasing the coupling of your code. You could use the pattern OpenSessionInView, EJBs Components or Injection/AOP transaction controller.
5. To delete an entity you will need to attach it first. You could use the getReference method: `Entity justId = entityManager.getReference(Entity.class, ID)`.

Take a look at this material that will help you understand about the JPA basics: http://uaihebert.com/jpa-mini-book-first-steps-and-detailed-concepts/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, the first step (I think) will be a creating DAO class for `Subject`, moving all methods like `get`, `fetchall` and so on into that DAO class and make at most one instance of EntityManagerFactory per DAO class. Right?

Comment: One EntityMagerFactory per Application. And your should not allow your entity to use a EntityManager, but only the EntityManager should use the Entity.

Comment: That's why I need the DAO classess? To make EntityManager use entities and not vice-versa. Right?

Comment: Yes, an entity should not access an EntityManager.